# TestContainers+Windows10+WSL2+Docker+Idea: Could not find a valid Docker environment

Tags: windows, docker, intellij-idea, wsl-2, testcontainers

I use Win 10 and Docker on WSL2.

**WSL Docker settings**

docker --version
Docker version 24.0.5, build 24.0.5-0ubuntu1~20.04.1

I added `"hosts": ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"]` to daemon.json
/etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
  "default-address-pools":
  [
    {"base": "199.160.20.0/24", "size": 26}
  ],
  "hosts": ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"]
}
```

So  curl http://localhost:2375/version returns following for wsl and terminal in windows

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"Platform":{"Name":""},"Components":[{"Name":"Engine","Version":"24.0.5",
```

For WSL in /lib/systemd/system/docker.service I changed ExecStart like this
`ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock`

For WSL I ran command `sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`

Docker is running on WSL (started as `sudo dockerd`):

```
INFO[2023-09-11T12:30:08.122438500+03:00] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock
INFO[2023-09-11T12:30:08.122478400+03:00] API listen on 127.0.0.1:2375
```

**.testcontainers.properties**

I added the following settings in .testcontainers.properties

```
docker.client.strategy=org.testcontainers.dockerclient.EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy
client.ping.timeout=65
docker.host=tcp\://localhost\:2375
```

**IDEA settings**

I have the following settings in IDEA

[image]

[image: Docker plugin settings]

When I ran automated tests using Testconteiners I got the error

```
2023-09-11 13:21:37.050 ERROR 22668 --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       : Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
2023-09-11 13:21:37.050 ERROR 22668 --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       :     NpipeSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception TimeoutException (Timeout waiting for result with exception). Root cause NoSuchFileException (\\.\pipe\docker_engine)
2023-09-11 13:21:37.050 ERROR 22668 --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       :     NpipeSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception TimeoutException (Timeout waiting for result with exception). Root cause NoSuchFileException (\\.\pipe\docker_engine)
2023-09-11 13:21:37.050 ERROR 22668 --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       : As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue
```

Any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: Hello, could you please specify if the problem is the same as described in [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-331522)? If yes, please let me know; I'll add the details you mentioned to the issue and ask a responsible developer to take a look at this.

Comment: Hi, @OlgaM! Yes, it's the same problem. It's IDEA 2021.2.2

Comment: Is it possible to check if the problem persists in the latest available release IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.1? There were a lot of changes between these two versions, so the problem could have already been fixed.

Comment: I installed Idea comunity edition 2023.2.1 and it found docker on wsl `Found Docker environment with Environment variables, system properties and defaults. Resolved dockerHost=tcp://localhost:2375
2023-09-13 08:55:26.000  INFO 14640 --- [           main] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : Docker host IP address is localhost
2023-09-13 08:55:26.451  INFO 14640 --- [           main] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : Connected to docker: 
  Server Version: 24.0.5
  API Version: 1.43
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
  Total Memory: 12608 MB`

Comment: I'm glad to hear it! Since the problem is fixed in the newer IDE version, please, consider leaving a comment in the YT issue you made so we can close it.

Comment: So there is no workaround for IDEA 2021.2.2, isn't it? I use IDEA 2021.2.2 Ultimate Edition and I'm not allowed to use higher versions.

Comment: For me, it looks like the first line (`docker.client.strategy=org.testcontainers.dockerclient.EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy`) in the `.testcontainers.properties` file could be a reason for the problem. Could you please check if there is any difference if you remove this option and set up the environment variables instead?